# Passing parameters when calling a method using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, parameter-passing

The method that is called looks something like this:

```
        protected void Scoped(Action<Context, Repository> fn, bool isValid)
        {
            // this is another Scoped() method
            Scoped(context => 
            {
                // do something
                fn(context, repo);
            });
        }
```

From an unit test, I'm trying to call this method but I don't know how to pass the isValid boolean. It doesn't let me pass it as this:

```
            Scoped((context, repo), true =>
            {
                //do something
            });
```

What's the right way of passing the arguments?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"true" is a parameter after the action, not in it :

```
Scoped((context, repo) => doSomething, true)
```